# Public method invisible to other class in same package

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, datepicker, android-dialogfragment

I have two classes. One is my main activity and the other one a helper method which is supposed to open an Android DatePicker. Everything worked fine so far, except if I want to retrieve the date from the date picker class. Here are my classes:

```
    // This is the class that creates the date picker
    package com.strom.myapp;

    import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
    import android.app.Dialog;
    import android.app.DialogFragment;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.widget.DatePicker;

    import java.util.Calendar;



    public class DefaultDatePicker extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

        private String returnDate;


        public String getReturnDate() {
            return returnDate;
        }

        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

            return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
            returnDate = String.valueOf(dayOfMonth) +
                    "." +
                    String.valueOf(monthOfYear) +
                    "." +
                    String.valueOf(year) +
                    ", 00:00";
        }
    }
```

And here is the main activity

```
package com.strom.myapp;

import android.app.DialogFragment;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;


public class BalanceScreen extends ActionBarActivity {

private String payDate;

// ... omitted code ...

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.action_payDate) {

            DialogFragment datePicker = new DefaultDatePicker();
            datePicker.show(getFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
            payDate = datePicker.getReturnDate();

            return true;
        }


// ... omitted code ...

}
```

The getter-method 'datePicker.getReturnDate();' is not accessible from the main activity, even though they are in the same package. I don't see why this shouldn't work. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i will suggest you to replace:

```
DialogFragment datePicker = new DefaultDatePicker();
```

with

```
DefaultDatePicker datePicker = new DefaultDatePicker();
```

Because your method getReturnDate is declared in DefaultDatePicker, and not in DialogFragment.

Comment: This, I was too slow.

Answer (score 0):

You can cast `datePicker` (which refeers an instance of *DefaultDatePicker*) to `DefaultDatePicker` to invoke methods which are specific to `DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener`.

```
((DefaultDatePicker)datePicker).getReturnDate()
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a public variable to your activity say

```
public String dateFromPicker = "";
```

In `DefaultDatePicker` method `onDateSet` do this

```
((BalanceScreen)getActivity()).dateFromPicker = returnDate;
```